# Opening Attribute Table by using ArcGIS Pro SDK, WPF and C#

Tags: c#, arcgis-pro, wpf, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am trying to display an attribute table for a selected layer. I have access to attribute table but I can not pass the ArcGIS table to the DataGrid I created in xaml.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_A_Table" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" 
Margin="10,48,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280"/>
```

Do you have any idea?

```
public void create_Layer()
        {
            string shp_path = this.ComboBox_shpfiles.Text;
            int indexNumber = 0;

            if (shp_path != null && shp_path != string.Empty)
            {
                System.Uri shp_filepath = new System.Uri(@shp_path);
                QueuedTask.Run(() =>
                {
                    var shp_layer = LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer(shp_filepath, MapView.Active.Map, indexNumber, shp_path.Substring(16));
                    //Get the active map view.
                    var mapView = MapView.Active;
                    if (mapView == null)
                        return Task.FromResult(false);
                    else
                    {

                        var selectedLayer = mapView.GetSelectedLayers()[0];
                        //var tableContent = TableControlContentFactory.Create(selectedLayer);



                        if (selectedLayer is ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping.FeatureLayer)
                        {
                            ArcGIS.Core.Data.Table a_table = (selectedLayer as FeatureLayer).GetTable();

                            DataGrid_A_Table.DataContext = a_table; // This line is not working

                            int gugu = a_table.GetCount(); //I can the count of rows here
                            MessageBox.Show(gugu.ToString());
                        }

                        //Zoom to the selected layers in the TOC
                        return mapView.ZoomToAsync(selectedLayer);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

I tried to cast ArcGIS.Core.Data.Table to System.Windows.Documents.Table but did not work

I am getting wrong thread exception.